# Implement a link back to a search result page from one of its clicked on results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Implement a link back to a search result page from one of its clicked on results.

What I am trying to do is pass a search query via a back link and to display the result in a view and then run the search query auto.

```
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { searchString= TempData["lastSearchString"] } )
```

I am having trouble trying to implement this concept .

Comment: What about the action link is not working?  as long as there is a controller parameter called query, and the ViewBag.Query is a valid query string, this should be working.  Which part is breaking down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is javascript a possibility?

This should retain the search results and text entered. Not sure if it works on all browsers however.

```
<A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1);">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
tempdata["lastSearchString"]=searchString;
}
```

in your view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { searchString= tempdata["lastSearchString"] } )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the code puts the search result, back in the search box after you go back to the index view - However does not redisplay the search result.

Comment: that's why, you should not use java script go-back, use action-link like i posted, if you still have problem, paste your view here, so that i can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it using Session variables or by storing a cookie

Comment: Is there away to implement it without session variables or by storing a cookie.

Comment: I have tryed session state before but had no luck.